# Multiple closures, same function different name, set() changes all values

Tags: javascript, closures

I declare 5 closures very similarly:

```
_nameFilter = (function () { _v = ""; return {"set": function(v) {_v = v;},"get":    function() {return _v;}};})();
_dateFilter = (function () { _v = ""; return {"set": function(v) {_v = v;},"get": function() {return _v;}};})();
_dateStartFilter = (function () { _v = ""; return {"set": function(v) {_v = v;},"get": function() {return _v;}};})();
_dateEndFilter = (function () { _v = ""; return {"set": function(v) {_v = v;},"get": function() {return _v;}};})();
_friendFilter = (function () { _v = ""; return {"set": function(v) {_v = v;},"get": function() {return _v;}};})();
_creatorFilter = (function () { _v = ""; return {"set": function(v) {_v = v;},"get": function() {return _v;}};})();
```

TLDR: 5 closures with one internal variable and a get() and set() method.

I then pass each to an arbitrary function and attempt to set() them individually based on a form in the HMTL. However, whenever I change one, it changes them all.

This is pseudo code for a more complex function but this it the important part.

```
function setFilter(filterVar, fieldID) {
    filterVar.set($(fieldID).val());
    console.log(_nameFilter); // Both (and all) of these variables are being set
    console.log(_dateFilter); // to the same value of the fieldID of _nameFilter.
}

setFilter(_nameFilter);
```

I have two questions: why is it doing this? And how can I stop it?

Thanks!

Comment: use var _v instead of just _v

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are using _v by itself so it becomes a global variable.  You would need var _v